# Google.com pages show as unsecure when connecting https

Tags: google-chrome, security, https, tls

I recently reinstalled windows 7 on my machine, ran automatic updates, everything up to date. Downloaded and installed google chrome. Whenever I browse to a google site (google.com, myaccount.google.com, etc) the url bar shows https in red with a line through it and it reads not secure.

I have tried several other sites (two of which were banks, cause I figured they would be using most current tls) and am able to send/receive https successfully securely.

Is there something I'm missing. I'm not real sure what else it could be? Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure you run all the windows updates.  There are various crypto and hash algorithms in TLS that have been deprecated, and support added to Win7 in later service packs.

Comment: check your system's date & time setting

Answer (score 0):

google.com's certificate is issued by GeoTrust, so I think you lack the GeoTrust Global CA certificate. Download it from https://www.geotrust.com/au/resources/root-certificates/ and import it, by following [this](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/manage-trusted-root-certificates-windows) guide. Restart chrome and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

@Adrien's comment about making sure all updates had been installed was correct. I had installed two waves of updates, but there was a third, and it contained the updated crypto and hash algorithms for tls.